# Loading an embedded map from website to java application

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-maps

i have necessity to load an embedded map from an url, to a java application (using java).
The site is http://www.atm-mi.it/it/Giromilano/Pagine/default.aspx, and i wanted it with all overlays created after the form submit "Calcola".
This map is generated by Javascript, but how can i get information from my Java-Android Application?

Comment: When you say "load a map", what do you expect your Java application to get?

Comment: Said website does *not* use google maps. You should check if they provide an API to make your job easier.

Comment: i expect the map you see in the middle of the website, but if it isn't possible, i can extract some information from it, like coordinates of points that constitute the result path. But i don't know how